Why memento is required while originator can do the job?
One thing is disturbing me about the Memento Design Pattern.
Why should we use the Memento object to replicate the Originator state to store it for future restoration? Can't we use the Originator object directly for the same purpose?
Don't you think the Memento adds extra complexity to achieve the purpose?
e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-memento-design-pattern
public class TextEditor {

    private TextWindow textWindow;
    private TextWindowState savedTextWindow;

    public TextEditor(TextWindow textWindow) {
        this.textWindow = textWindow;
    }

    public void write(String text) {
        textWindow.addText(text);
    }

    public String print() {
        return textWindow.getCurrentText();
    }

    public void hitSave() {
        savedTextWindow = textWindow.save();
    }

    public void hitUndo() {
        textWindow.restore(savedTextWindow);
    }
}

public class TextWindowState {

    private String text;

    public TextWindowState(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

public class TextWindow {

    private StringBuilder currentText;

    public TextWindow() {
        this.currentText = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public String getCurrentText() {
        return currentText.toString();
    }

    public void addText(String text) {
        currentText.append(text);
    }

    public TextWindowState save() {
        return new TextWindowState(currentText.toString());
    }

    public void restore(TextWindowState save) {
        currentText = new StringBuilder(save.getText());
    }
}

Don't you think we can replace TextWindowState by TextWindow and the whole thing is good to go?

Memento object stores state, but does not have other responsibilities of Originator. If Originator is large in size, holds non-GC resources, is a Singleton, or is otherwise non-copyable, memento allows to save multiple different states of Originator without affecting Originator or its clients.
As per linked article this allows building an Undo tree. Memento is also useful for persistence and synchronization (for example over network).
In your simplified example, TextWindow may be copied, but in any real UI framework a copy of a Window either:

is impossible
or creates a new window on screen as an undesirable side-effect
or allocates valuable system resources

